# I want to blur out a part of a video

Tags: adobe-photoshop, blur, video

How can I do this without separately touching up all 150 frames (layers) in Photoshop. I'm using the blur tool.

Comment: I think you can use Youtube...

Answer (score 3):

***To my knowledge***

There's frankly no easy way to do this. Its the nature of video and Photoshop is still pretty basic for animation. If you were using After Effects you could add a blurred layer mask over the timeline.

In Photoshop this question addresses how to blur all layers beneath it: [Photoshop: how to create an adjustment layer that blurs all layers below?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/7498/how-to-create-an-adjustment-layer-that-blurs-all-layers-below)

Now that is only going to be really helpful if the part that needs blurring is static. If its moving around then it becomes even more complicated. Even in After Effects, much like Flash, you would have to go in and set keyframes every so often (or use Advanced Motion Tracking) to move the layer mask around.

There could be a solution someone else has come up with though

Comment: You can use mask and matte effects to blur stuff fairly quickly and effectively if the object is stationary and  nothing else moves in front of it that you don't want blurred. You can go the crappy looking route and make a colored blur to archive that 'cops' effect. Then set keyframes and move a large mask around with an object. You are right that if you only want one object blurred but nothing else and it is moving a lot or has motion in front of it a lot your kind of out of luck . You can do things 3-10 frames at a time and save some time but even that takes a while.

Comment: @JackMcE can you set matte effects and keyframe in Photoshop? Or you mean if in After Effects type of software?

Comment: I was talking in video editors. After Effects, Premier Pro, Final Cut, Vegas or similar software. Like you said "quickest" way to the OP's intended result (if they have to use photoshop) is to use a layer or adjustment mask placed above all the layers they want effected. You could sorta keyframe that using groups maybe but it still gets messy quickly.

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient (well, okay, least inefficient) way to accomplish this in Photoshop would probably be to make a selection over the part you want to blur, then feather it a few pixels (depending on the size of your image) and apply a Gaussian blur. Don't deselect, and keep the selection tool (marquee, lasso, whatever you used) active so you can move the selection without disturbing the image.

Move the CTI to the next frame, move the selection if you have to, and use Cmd/Ctl-F to repeat the blur. Go to the next frame and repeat until you've done them all.

This kind of thing is best done in After Effects or Premier. It's not the sort of task Photoshop's video capabilities were really intended to serve. Look on the bright side, though. Rotoscoping used to be done by hand, frame by frame, on film:

> One classic use of traditional rotoscoping was in the original three Star Wars films, where it was used to create the glowing lightsaber effect, by creating a matte based on sticks held by the actors. To achieve this, editors traced a line over each frame with the prop, then enlarged each line and added the glow.

*From the [Wikipedia article on Rotoscoping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotoscoping)*

Answer (score 0):

Photoshop is not the best tool to do this.
In After effects or Premiere, you can use a blur overlay which actually tracks the motion of an object.

Here is useful link:https://forums.adobe.com/thread/711706?start=0&tstart=0